# Where I should create a directory for nodejs apps?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I'm not familiar with Ubuntu. I want to make some nodejs apps for testing, now I'm confused where I should create a directory for it.

I have searched in google and I found every one saying

`sudo apt-get install nodejs npm`

and create `server.js` file and put this code `blah blah` and run `npm server.js` etc.

But where I should create this file? 
Where I should create directory?

I know about `/var/www/html` but there are my other php projects here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For development use a subdirectory if your user home dir.

E.g., `~/projects/test-project` like somebody suggested.

You would usually add this to git, too. E.g.

```
mkdir -p ~/projects/test-project
cd ~/projects/test-project
# add your server.js now
git init
git add .
git commit -a -m 'here goes nothing'
```

For testing, you might wanna do something closer to what your deployment site looks like. Usually it's `/srv/project-name` or `/var` like you've suggested.

Those directories usually don't exist and you cannot access them by default, so you create them with sudo. Example:

```
sudo mkdir -p /srv/my-project
sudo chown `whoami`:`whoami` /srv/my-project
cd /srv/my-project
git clone ~/projects/test-project .
```

Now you can test both local dev version and the test one.

P.S. You should try [nvm.sh](http://nvm.sh) for installing node, much more versions and fresher ones.

Comment: Perfect, fully detailed answer, this is what I was looking. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can place the projects anywhere you like. I usually put them in ~/projects.

Running `npm start` will fire up a web server running at http://localhost:8080, so there's no need for /var/www if you're just doing some testing.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid permission issue, put the file in your **Document** folder.
You can run the **npm** command  from this folder. Fore expl create a folder "nodejs" inside your Document Folder and put your code here.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a project directory anywhere in ubuntu (where you have permissions). For example home directory or your desktop.
`cd` into this directory and create a server.js file that contains your code.

You can either use the node server or http-server module to serve your application.
Link to the http-server module [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)